# PDF creation library in ActionScript 2.0

Tags: flash, pdf, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have this application authored in Flash CS4, and it uses ActionScript 2.0 due to the reason that I am not the original developer. I am just updating it for another client.

The thing is, this application previously compiled a PDF using Director, and now the Director file is giving script errors. I have seen that there are PDF libraries available for AS3.0, but what about AS2.0? Does anyone know of a way to save text to a PDF using AS2.0, it does not have to be a library, just a way of saving a PDF on client side?

P.S. The application will always run client-side in a projector. And using PHP is not really an option.

Thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [blazePDF](http://www.blazepdf.com)...

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I am going to give it a try, will let you know what happens.

Comment: This is very helpful, but now I need a Flash wrapper to save the file to the user's computer. Any ideas? Google is NOT my friend today.

Comment: I have downloaded this, and everything works, except that the component does not draw the strings to the PDF "mock-up" in the component. Do you know if there is a method to call in order to update the page in the component itelf? When I save the output in TextEdit to a .pdf file, the .pdf shows up correct. Which means I just need to update the component.

Comment: The problem is I need to show the user how the PDF looks in the component, because that is what he will be expecting as it loads a nice PDF viewer.